# Align multiple images beside in Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script

after several hours of searching and try & error, I have to give up.
I got a google doc wich I fill up with some data from a google sheet.
Also I create some pie charts with the data and would like to align 2 (or even more) little charts (>200x200 px) inline beside eachother.
But I am not able to do it. :(

One single image, or chart isn´t any problem, but 2 or more seems to be pretty hard.

Thats why I picked up this option and Your experience as my last option.

Thank you very much for every hint and have a nice Day.

Michael

"Short" Code Sample:

**Step 1**: Open Google Sheet

```
var reportDataStorage = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/.../edit');
var sheet = reportDataStorage.getSheetByName(...);
```

**Step 2**: Create Table

```
var daten_besucher_nach_quelle = Charts.newDataTable()
    ...
    daten_besucher_nach_quelle.addRow([sheet.getRange('O'+y).getValue(), sheet.getRange('P'+y).getValue(), sheet.getRange('Q'+y).getValue(); sheet.getRange('R'+y).getValue()]);
    ...
    daten_besucher_nach_quelle.build();
```

**Step 3**: Create Chart from Table

```
var chart_besucher_nach_quelle = Charts.newPieChart()
    .setDataTable(daten_besucher_nach_quelle)
    .setDimensions(300, 300)
    ...
    .build();
```

**Step 4**: Append Image

```
body.appendImage(chart_besucher_nach_quelle.getAs('image/png'));
```

Is this enough?

Comment: could you provide a small code to test the situation ?

Comment: done. :) 
I hope the sample is enough.

Comment: I was hoping a code that could reproduce the issue without needing to rewrite a whole script, something with any shared images since the issue is not charts but image positioning.

Comment: It´s all about image positioning, but i am sorry i have no small sample, but during trying to create one, i realised, that i use body.appendImage. But this creates a new Paragraph each time, so i cant align 2 images beside with appendImage. I guess i should use insertImage, but i can´t find out how to do so. If you have a short hint for using insertImage i would be really happy, and maybe i can find my answer this way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: that's what I thought...Im just too lazy to write a test code... try if you can append an image to the current paragraph (the one with the first image), this should solve the problem.

Comment: try if you can append an image to the current paragraph (the one with the first image) - could you please explain this a little bit? I dont know what you mean.

Comment: I'll post a test as an answer... it will be more clear and easy to explain...

Comment: that would be great - thanks a lot!

Comment: Answer added, sorry for the delay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, when you insert an image in a document, a new paragraph is automatically added to the document's body.

This paragraph container is accessible using `image.getParent()` method. As soon as we get this paragraph we can add another image in it, this image will be directly aligned side by side (as long as the total width is less than the maximum size between margins).

Try this small simple code and see the result in the scren capture below :

```
function importImageTest(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var image1 = DriveApp.getFileById("0B3qSFd3iikE3TUFFLWY0ZWJjNzM2LWFiNDYtNGU1OC1hMGNhLTViM2UxNTBlMTE3Nw");// some image in my drive
  var image2 = DriveApp.getFileById("0B3qSFd3iikE3TUFFLWI3Y2JiOTU1LWM0OGYtNDVkMS05ZTRiLTkzNjQ5NDBlZGFkNA");
  var firstImage = body.appendImage(image1).setWidth(150).setHeight(100);// an arbitrary size
  var currentParagraph = firstImage.getParent();// the container of first image
  currentParagraph.asParagraph().appendInlineImage(image2).setWidth(150).setHeight(100);// add the second image to this parent paragraph
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `appendInlineImage` method is obsolete, now is called `insertInlineImage`